# Style reports of cucumber

Tags: cucumber, report, functional-testing, selenide

I have a problem, I am automating with cucumber, and I want create reports with all items after that the test run. In this moment, I have reports that dont give me information of failure or success test, only I can show the scenarios.This is the report:
[image]

and this is my code with de Cucumber configurartions, but I haven't found a plugin with all information.

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(plugin = {"usage", "html:target/cucumber"},
        features = {"./src/test/resources/com/proteccion/advance/viabilidad"},
        glue = {"com.proteccion.advance.viabilidad.steps"},
        format = {"json:target/cucumber.json"}            )
public class RunCucumber{}
```

I would Like something like this

[image]

If you can give me multiple reports' types I would greatly appreciate help

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Julian! I am not sure if it is can help but I was using Allure report for cucumber quite successful, so my suggestion is to try Allure report

https://docs.qameta.io/allure/#_cucumber_jvm

https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-cucumberjvm